# C How to split variable read from .txt file scanf

Tags: c, string, split, scanf

Can someone help me with this problem? I have a `.txt` file which I am reading using C as below via `fopen`. I can display the text as a variable to the screen which is good. However the text I am reading from the file is comma delimited. How can I split the string from the text file into two variables instead of one?

### example

username,password

I would like the end output to be

var1 = username
var2 = password

Here is my code.

```
inFile = fopen("logfile.txt", "r"); /*This opens the file */    
if (inFile == NULL)            /*Checks that the file exists*/ {        
    printf("\nThe file %c was not opened successfully.", fileName);     
    printf("\nPlease check that you entered the file name correctly.\n");       
    exit(1);    
}   
while (fscanf(inFile, "%s", text) !=EOF) /*Reads and displays the file*/        
    printf("%s\n", text);   
fclose(inFile);
```

Kind of fix

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <iostream>

int main (void) { 
    char *s; 
    char test[50];
    int i=0;
    char str[] = 
        "username,password";
    printf ("%s\n", str); 
    s = strtok (str, ","); 
    // 
    while (s != NULL) { 
        printf ("%s\n", s); 

        s = strtok (NULL, ","); 

} 
        system("pause");
    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: What you're probably looking for is `strtok`. Also, `fgets` would be more appropriate than `fscanf` in this case, because its use here might lead to a buffer overflow.

Comment: It is aconventional to put a comment between the condition and the `{` as in `if (condition) /* here */ {`.  The C compiler doesn't mind; your human audience are likely to find it confusing because it is unusual.

Comment: Why are you including `iostream` if it's a C application?

Comment: can anyone answer the question for me please. it was so I could include the system ("pause") function. Only been using C for 6 days.

Answer (score 3):

The `strtok` function is what you are looking for

Comment: not homework just messing around with differnt ways of storing passwords for my dialog app.

Comment: Well thanks I managed to get strok working but just one last question how do I store the splits into varriables. Sorry for the questions a newbie to C from PHP. Example of my code above.

Comment: Note that `strtok()` comes with its own problems, especially if the code is to be reusable. Fundamentally, you cannot safely use `strtok()` in a library function. If it's available, `strtok_r()` is OK for use in library functions instead. There are other issues common to `strtok()` and `strtok_r()`, such as they trample on the the string being analyzed (sometimes that doesn't matter, sometimes it does), and you can't tell which delimiter was found if there could be several, and they treat any sequence of delimiters as equivalent, so you can't have empty fields as in CSV: `field1,,field3`.

Comment: Passwords should **never** be stored in plaintext. Start with that.

Comment: its only for an experiement I am sure they will be encryoted by release time.

Answer (score 0):

The process is to use the `strtok` function. What the function does is change the delimiter (in this case a `,`) into a `\0` (null) character. It then passes back a pointer to the start of the string now terminated by the `\0`. If run again with a NULL passed into it, it will then split based on the delimiter again (if it exists), and pass back a pointer to the second portion of the string. The following is the code you need to add:

```
#include <string.h>
char* var1;
char* var2;
```

And then in your while loop:

```
{
    var1 = strtok(text,",");
    var2 = strtok(NULL,",");
    printf("%s<NOT A ','>%s\n", var1,var2);
}
```

What this is doing to the string text is as follows. When we get it from the file, `text` =

```
/------------------------------------\
|u|s|e|r|n|a|m|e|,|p|a|s|s|w|o|r|d|\0|
\------------------------------------/
```

The first line of the while loop changes it so that `text` =

```
/-------------------------------------\
|u|s|e|r|n|a|m|e|\0|p|a|s|s|w|o|r|d|\0|
\1------------------------------------/
```

Where `var1` points to the letter above the 1, thus `var1 = username`. Note that this means if you run a printf on `text`, you will also get username. After the second line, `text` =

```
/-------------------------------------\
|u|s|e|r|n|a|m|e|\0|p|a|s|s|w|o|r|d|\0|
\1------------------2-----------------/
```

And now `var1` points to a string "username" and `var2` points to the string "password". If you printf `text`, you will still get "username".

Note that if you were wanting to get more then two variables, you would want to have a safety catch making sure that strtok didn't return a `NULL` before you try and use the string.

Also note that if you modify `text`, you will also mess up `var1` and `var2`. I would suggest using a `strcpy` to another string if you wish to hold the information in a more permanent way.

Comment: Thanks peter a top answer I learned a lot from it and got it work god bless you.

Answer (score 0):

If your can make sure the filed delimiter is ',' and the input data only have two fields.
Because the `strtok` is not a reentrantable function so I usually use `scanf` insead of `strtok` when the intput data format is already know.

```
int re;
char line[200];
char usernme[100];
char password[100];
while (fgets(line, 200, inFile) != NULL)
{
    /*Reads and displays the file*/        
    re = sscane(line, "%[^","],%s", username, password);
    if(re == 2)
    {
        printf("Usarname = %s, Password = = %d\r\n", username, password);
    }
}
```